# How to match the first part of string with the two same substring?

Tags: python, regex

I have text as below,

```
<meta name="description" content="28日からは「天地始粛(てんちはじめてさむし)」。 「粛」にはおさまる、弱まる等の意味があり、夏の暑さもようやく落ち着いてくる頃とされています。">
<meta name="Keywords" content="天気,天気予報,気象,情報,台風,地震,津波,週間,ウェザー,ウェザーニュース,ウェザーニューズ,今日の天気,明日の天気"><meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:title" content="【天地始粛】音や景色から感じる秋の気配"><meta property="og:description" content="28日からは「天地始粛(てんちはじめてさむし)」。 「粛」にはおさまる、弱まる等の意味があり、夏の暑さもようやく落ち着いてくる頃とされています。"><meta property="og:url" content="https://weathernews.jp/s/topics/201807/300285/">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201807/201807300285_sns_img_A.jpg?1532940869">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="【天地始粛】音や景色から感じる秋の気配">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="28日からは「天地始粛(てんちはじめてさむし)」。 「粛」にはおさまる、弱まる等の意味があり、夏の暑さもようやく落ち着いてくる頃とされています。"><meta name="twitter:image" content="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201807/201807300285_sns_img_A.jpg?1532940869">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://weathernews.jp/s/topics/201807/300285/">
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://weathernews.jp/s/topics/201807/300285/amp.html">
<script async="async" src="https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js">
```

I used `pattern = re.compile(r'(https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/[0-9]+/.+)\?[0-9]+')` to match it, and I want to get `https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201807/201807300285_sns_img_A.jpg`, but I got

```
https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201807/201807300285_sns_img_A.jpg?1532940869"><meta name="twitter:title" content="【天地始粛】音や景色から感じる秋の気配"><meta name="twitter:description content="28日からは「天地始粛(てんちはじめてさむし)」。 「粛」にはおさまる、弱まる等の意味があり、夏の暑さもようやく落ち着いてくる頃とされています。"><meta name="twitter:image" content="https://smtgs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201807/201807300285_sns_img_A.jpg
```

how can I modify my Regex pattern?

Comment: Judging by your regex, you want to match the "?somedigitshere" part after .jpg, but then you say you don't want that. Which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

this captures the url until it reaches file extensions[inclusive],

```
(https:\/\/smtgvs\.weathernews\.jp\/s\/topics\/img\/\d+\/\w+\.[jpng]{3})
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/ts4EH3/3)

Comment: @mikezang check it now

Comment: Well, I changed to `(https:\/\/smtgvs\.weathernews\.jp\/s\/topics\/img\/\d+\/\w+\.(jpg|png))`, cause I need full URL, this way I got a list as `[https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201807/201807300285_sns_img_A.jpg, jpg]`, can I only get URL? I mean how can I omit `(` and `)` for `jpg|png`?

Comment: you want only url? you said on the question you need up to the extension?

Comment: Sorry, I need url not extension.

Comment: `https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201807/201807300285_sns_img_A`? specify the url you want?

Comment: sorry again, I need `https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201807/201807300285_sns_img_A.jpg` or `https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201807/201807300285_sns_img_A.png`

Comment: `(https:\/\/smtgvs\.weathernews\.jp\/s\/topics\/img\/\d+\/\w+\.(jpg|png))` will do it. check it in regex101.com, take yhe full match.

Comment: I knew this way, is there any other ways to only get full URLs?

Comment: icame to know i actually don't get you, try this or edit your question `(https:\/\/smtgvs\.weathernews\.jp\/s\/topics\/img\/\d+\/\w+\.[jpng]{3})`

Comment: It is Wonderful!